# Partially hardcoded textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have requirement to create a username textbox in asp.net.
where the format would be like:

```
DOMAIN-NAME/username
```

Now the `DOMAIN-NAME` should be by default text that is hardcoded and non-editable. User can enter only username but cannot delete `DOMAIN-NAME`.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the domain to be hardcoded and non-editable, you need to put it on the server.

On page_load:

```
string domainName = @"DEFAULT-NAME/";
string userName = TextBoxId.Value; //do some server side checks on value before processing it though
string finalUserName = domainName + userName;
```

Even if you put a secondary readonly textbox on the page, never trust that the value received by the non-editable textbox is what you expect it to be, because POST variables can be easily manipulated. Add the domain on the server, and display it - if you need to - on the page in a label near the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need both of them in the same text box? 
Wont a non editable (inactive) `textbox` for domain name and an editable `textbox` for username do?

Or else you can put both in the same text box. 
But make sure the string

> domain name/

isnt deleted by user by using validations (`JQUERY` or `Javascript`)

Answer (score 0):

On click of the text box remove the Domain-Name and then when they Leave the textBox append the Domain-Name. Alternatively put the DOMAIN-NAME into a label and put the textBox aside it?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the domain name in a Label to the left of the text box.

If it absolutely has to show the domain in the textbox, you will have to right some javascript to mask it.

There could be code out there that would help, for example, if you are using JQuery, this kind of thing:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: The link you gave is very close to my requirement.
Thanks.
Will try implement this n see.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A textbox is either disabled, which means that you can't edit any of the contents, or enabled, which means that you can edit all of the contents. Most applications that have a requirement like yours use a label in front of the textbox to show the non-editable part.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Show label before text box and use code by @LonWolf while reading

Option 2: Show text box background image and left padding. In image you can provide DEFAULT-Name

Option 3: use some jquery plugin like here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms, see extending form control which shows pretty nice text box prefix and suffix

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to look at the requirements as: "It appears that there is a text box with a hard-coded domain name." then try this:

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">

span.fakeTextBox{
    border: 2px inset #EBE9ED;
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 3px; 
    font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;
}

span.fakeTextBox input{
    border: none;
    outline:none;
}

</style>

<body>

<span class="fakeTextBox">
MyDomain\<input type="text" >
<span>

</body>
</html>
```

The users will never know the difference